# How to navigate user to its related store?

Tags: google-play, app-store, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, appgallery-connect

On our website , we are able to navigate users to their related stores according to device's os .

> for ios we send them to AppStore

> for android we navigate them to PlayStore

i wonder how can we navigate them to App Gallery if the user is using a Huawei mobile device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i wonder how can we navigate them to App Gallery if the user is using a Huawei mobile device ?

You may use [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/App-linking).

App Linking enables you to create a unified download link for your app so that when users tap the link, they will be redirected to the app download page on their local app store installed on their device. For example, App Store is opened for iOS devices, AppGallery is opened for Android devices with AppGallery installed, and Google Play is opened for Android devices without AppGallery. This feature helps you boost app downloads and increase your user base.

For more details,pls kindly refer to [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-unifiedlinking-0000001070790553).

Comment: tnx i dismissed this page on developer website